# Bidirectional Replication on Postgresql 9.3

Tags: java, postgresql, database-replication, high-availability, bucardo

I am using Postgres 9.3 on my production servers. I would like to achieve high availability of Postgres DB using Master-Master configuration where each master would run in an Active-Active mode with bidirectional replication.

I have 2 Java Spring REST web-services pointed to 2 separate database engines each having their own storage. Both web services point to its own database plus the other one in HA configuration.

Now if any one of the Databases fails, I want the active database server to work and when the failed one recover, the data should be synced back to the recovered one.

I tried doing bidirectional replication using Bucardo 5.3.1 but the recovered database does not get updated with the new data and Bucardo syncs need to be kicked again. (see bug: https://github.com/bucardo/bucardo/issues/88)

Is there any way I can achieve this with some other bi-directional replication tool?

Or is there any other way where I can have with 2 Postgres engines pointing to a shared storage running in Active-Active configuration?

Answer (score 1):

2nd Quadrant released Postgres BDR which is a patched version of PostgreSQL that can do multimaster replication using logical WAL decoding. You will find more informations here : https://www.2ndquadrant.com/fr/resources/bdr/

Comment: I don't think BDR works with Postgres 9.3. Also, I am running Postgres 9.3 in production. Replacing it with a patched version is not feasible for me at the moment.

Comment: Yes, BDR won't work on postgres 9.3... It works from 9.4 but anyway, you have to uninstall it to install the patched version...
I can't help you more...

Answer (score 0):

I have finally decided to move to Enterprise DB of Postgres (a paid licence) that provides replication tools via GUI which are easy to use and configure.